# How to fix "IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services"

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I can't find the source of this error ( "IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services") I see in my logcat.  Sorry, I've pasted much of the logcat but the main error is in **bold**.

Note that the first reference to my code in the logcat error listing is an AsyncTask that is itself called from an IntentService that is called from a BroadcastReceiver.

> 04-17 07:46:03.163: W/dalvikvm(23525): threadid=24: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x417582a0) 04-17 07:46:03.173:
>   D/AccountsActivity(23525): onRequestDone 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground() 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   **E/AndroidRuntime(23525): Caused by:
>   android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver
>   components are not allowed to bind to services** 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.bindService(ContextImpl.java:178)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.my_package.ServerRequests$11.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:378)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.my_package.ServerRequests$11.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:1)
>   04-17 07:46:03.163: W/dalvikvm(23525): threadid=24: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x417582a0) 04-17 07:46:03.173:
>   D/AccountsActivity(23525): onRequestDone 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525): java.lang.RuntimeException: An
>   error occured while executing doInBackground() 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 04-17
>   07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525): Caused by:
>   android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver
>   components are not allowed to bind to services 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext.bindService(ContextImpl.java:178)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:192)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:217)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:836)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.my_package.ServerRequests$11.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:378)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   com.my_package.ServerRequests$11.doInBackground(ServerRequests.java:1)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 04-17 07:46:03.178:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   04-17 07:46:03.178: E/AndroidRuntime(23525):    ... 5 more

The reference to "doInBackground" in the logcat is the only reference to my (not Android OS) code, and is only a Google Cloud Endpoint call:

```
uEndpoint.doRegistration(registrationId).execute();
```

No broadcast receiver I've defined has any explicit "bindService" call in it.

Where could I be illegally binding to a service?  Any ideas on where to look to trace down this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I've done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from incorrect usage of `GoogleAccountCredential` in an IntentService. The IntentService gets its Context object from the BroadcastReceiver that started it.  This BroadcastReceiver has a "ReceiverRestrictedContext".  Using this restricted  context in

```
GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context,.,.)  //-- this context was a "ReceiverRestrictedContext"
```

doesn't throw an exception until the credential gets used in an endpoint execution.

I fixed it by using

```
GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(getApplicationContext(),.,.)
```

in the IntentService.